# Sabayon 16 - MySQL Server unable to start

Tags: mysql, gentoo, sabayon

After installing Sabayon 16, I needed to install MySQL Server. I have followed two tutorials, but both of them fails to me. The first tutorial says to install `dev-db/mysql` and then execute `sudo /usr/bin/mysql_install_db –basedir=/usr` but an error saying the command was not found appears.

I found out that the command above is an script located at `usr/share/mysql/scrips`. I have executed it, trillions of messages appeared but now I cannot start `mysql` or `mariadb`. The error is

> unable to execute /etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory

but listing `/usr/init.d` shows me `mysql`.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sabayon is based in systemd. To start the service you have to do `systemctl start mysqld`. The reference to MySQL manual is [systemctl_Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-management-using-systemd.html)

Comment: I guess I've tried that too, but the same error happened. I'm using Debian now, but soon I will install Sabayon and test again, then I'll comment the result here.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. I hadn't used "mysqld", but "mysql" only.